# JBoss 6 Cluster Node register & deregister listener in deployed application

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss6.x, infinispan, jgroups

I have a cluster over jboss6 AS in domain mode. I have an application deployed in it. My application need to have a listener(callback) when a new node become member of the cluster and  also when gets removed. Is there a way to get the member node list and to add such a listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to get define a clustered cache in the configuration and get access to it from your code (see [example](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/InfinispanIntegrationInAS6)). With the cache available, you can call `cache.getCacheManager().addListener(Object)` that can listen for `org.infinispan.notifications.cachemanagerlistener.annotation.ViewChanged`. See [listener documentation](http://infinispan.org/docs/5.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_listeners_and_notifications) for more info.